Why does the net crossing of edge band through fermi surface determine whether the edge current changes under uniform electric field?
In Vanderbilt's book Berry Phase in Electronic Stucture, he used the argument that the current induced by shifting fermi level is given by
$\Delta I=\int_{k_1}^{k_2} \frac{dk}{2\pi}(-ev_g)=\frac{-e}{2\pi h}\int_{k_1}^{k_2}\frac{dE}{dk}dk=E_2-E_1$
where we assume the fermi-energy is moved from $E(k_1)$ to $E(k_2)$ and $v_g$ is the group velocity. He further used this result to calculate the edge current of an insulator under electric field. Although I don't have a problem with it per se, it seems to contradict my understanding I learned from general solid state if Fermi level lies inside a (bulk) band, the bulk is conducting because we can excite electrons with electric field to nearby state. Since the bulk band can't be "chiral", shouldn't the net crossing of Fermi level be 0 always?
My vague suspicion of the discrepancy of the two reasoning. In my solid state class, the heuristic argument is talking about dynamically electrically exciting an electron whereas the book is referring to weather the ground state has net current.
